# vb.net - How to get value from each line in richtextbox and show each values into textboxes

Tags: vb.net

i have a question in my code, Question is 
How to get value from each line in richtextbox and show each values into textboxes?

my code is :

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Results As String
Private Sub UpdateText()
    Dim xList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
    Results = Results.Replace(vbLf, "")
    Dim LineSplit() As String = Results.Split(vbCr)
    For Each xLine As String In LineSplit
        If xLine <> "" Then
            xList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(xLine.Split("=")(0), xLine.Split("=")(1).Trim.Replace(" ", "")))
        End If
    Next
    'do some work here to put the values in the right textboxes


End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    UpdateText()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Results = RichTextBox1.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Example Picture]

sorry for my bad english, i am from Indonesia, thanks..

Comment: How do you decide which line value goes in which `TextBox`? Do you have a `List(Of TextBox)`? Another reference source? The `TextBox` Tag? TabIndex? This is the only thing that matters here. The `RichTextBox` already has a `.Lines` property (string array) which accounts for its lines of text (separated by a LineFeed).

Comment: First line in richtextbox goes to first textbox, like the example picture, first line goto first textbox, second line goto second textbox

Comment: What defines one `TextBox` as "First" or "Second"?

Comment: In top left is first textbox next to it is second textbox, under first textbox is 7th textbox and next to it is 8th textbox

Comment: This is a visual reference (something you see with your eyes). Code is blind. How does your code establish the `TextBox` objects order?

Comment: I get the code from another website, i dont know what should i do after i get UpdateText() , should i discontinue my project? Im so confused with that code xD

Comment: Why would you discontinue your project? Think about it for a moment. You have a value in `Line(0)`. You have to assign that value to a TextBox, so you have to write something like `TextBox0.Text = Line(0)`, then `TextBox1.Text = Line(1)` etc. It would be really easy if you had a `List(Of TextBox)`. You probably don't, thus you have to find out a method to give an order to your TextBox controls. Find out a way to give a code-oriented order to your objects, and I'll help you with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your answer, but i dont understand in List(Of TextBox), is that like split or something?

Comment: If don't know what a `List(of [Something])` is, find another method. I can't give you a tutorial on this (but you can find many around the net). Focus on what you already know (In a previous comment I already gave you a couple of hints on how you could proceed).

Comment: Thank you for your time, appreciate that, i will learn List(Of [Something]), and iam sorry for wasting your time,,

Comment: No problem. See: [MSDN - List<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). -- [VB.Net - Iniialize a List](https://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list-vbnet). -- [VB.Net - List Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet). -- [How to use VB.NET List](http://vb.net-informations.com/collections/list.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of List you could loop over controls of Textbox type.

If number of lines is Always equal to number of textboxes you could loop over your lines or textboxes or even do a static for x=0 to 11 then simply put line x into textbox x.

As we don't know how you named these textboxes I'll show you a way that should work for you:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim counter As Integer
    For Each controlOnForm In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf controlOnForm Is TextBox Then
            if counter <12 then 'depending how you ordered them you may need to fix this sign
                controlOnForm.text = TextBox1.Lines(counter).Split("=")(1)
                counter += 1
            end if
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```